# Python - Getting "TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'" when trying to sort on 2 columns on a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have the DataFrame below and when I try to sort it by "Country" and "Sample" together, I get this "**TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'**" error. If I try to sort only on "Country" or only on "Sample" it works fine, but it presents that TypeError when I try to sort on both. Any help is appreciated.

```
df_sorted = df.sort_values(by=['Country','Sample'])
```

df_sorted =

```
    ID          Country Measurement  Sample     On/Off 

0   1234567890  Denmark 38           Sample 2   On 
95  2345678901  Denmark 12           Sample 1   On 
96  xyz789      Brazil  333          Sample 2   Off 
97  abc123      Brazil  50           Sample 6   Off 
98  def456      Brazil  44           Sample 3   Off
```

Comment: Which version of pandas and numpy are you using? I cannot reproduce.

Comment: @MichaelRuth using pip list I see -- pandas 1.0.5, numpy 1.19.0. Using Python 3.8.4

Comment: I'm on pandas v1.2.2, maybe there's a version issue

Comment: I upgraded to v1.2.4. Still getting same error. Looking around to see if there is something specific to the data in those columns.

Comment: Ok, I think I solved it but not sure what happened. I converted the 2 sort columns and the ID column to type str and it worked. I used    df['Country'] = df['Country'].astype(str) and df['Sample'] = df['Sample'].astype(str) to convert them to str. I guess there is something in the data types that caused the sort to not work (????). Would like to understand better what happened.

Comment: @Tom before casting the columns to `str`, were they of `category` type?

Comment: @Uts not sure I understand the question. When I printed the dtype for those columns it showed them to be```Object```